# Powershell Map Network Drive, write file to it but Notepad fails to find file

Tags: windows, powershell, mapped-drive

My Powershell script:

```
New-PSDrive -Name J -Root \\myserver\mypath -PSProvider FileSystem
"test" | Out-File J:\test.txt
Get-Content -Path J:\test.txt
notepad J:\test.txt
```

J drive maps ok, the file gets created, Get-Content can read it BUT notepad (or any .exe) cannot see the file.

What should I do to make the drive mapping visible to other executables run within the script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/New-PSDrive) by default creates drives that are visible only to *PowerShell commands*, in the same session.

**To create a regular mapped drive that *all* processes see, use the `-Persist` switch**, in which case you're restricted to the usual *single-letter* drive names (such as `J:` in your example).

Note: Despite the switch's name, the resulting mapping is only *persistent* (retained across OS sessions) if you either invoke it directly from the global scope of your PowerShell session (possibly by dot-sourcing a script that contains the `New-PSDrive` call from there) or explicitly use `-Scope Global`.

Otherwise, the mapping goes out of scope (is removed) along with the scope in which it was defined.